# Different results in training and evaluation of the same batch in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

How it is possible to get into the following situation?

```
In[20] model.test_on_batch(x, y)
Out[20]: [4.861001, 0.0]
In[21]: model.train_on_batch(x, y)
Out[21]: [0.019215763, 0.99609375]
```

The two output values correspond to the binary crossentropy and the binary accuracy respectively.

Namely, the training and testing results of a model on the *same batch* are radically different. The training results are presumably the good ones. The predictions (with `model.predict`) are not correct either.

Running Keras 2.2.4 under Tensorflow 1.8.0.

Comment: Do you know about `overfitting` and `high variance`?

Comment: @RudolfMorkovskyi Notice that I am refering to testing and training with exactly the **same batch**. I don't think that your comments apply here.

Comment: I have discovered that there was a bug in Tensorflow 1.8.0. Updating to Tensorflow 1.11 solved the problem. I leave the question though because the answer might be nevertheless useful for the future for somebody else.

Answer (score 2):

This is completely normal if you use a model that has Dropout or BatchNormalization layers, as these have different behavior during training and testing times. If you add any regularization terms then these will be disabled during testing and it will affect any loss you get from `model.evaluate`